# Find and Replace in C#.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have one string such as Date which has the value of Dates. Below is a sample value:

```
string Date = 05;
```

When Date is between 01 and 09, Date value should ignore "0". For example it should be "5".
     If it is "20" means then it should not ignore "0".

How to do this in C#?

Comment: Question makes no sense. What exactly are you asking. What are you searching for and what are you replacing with???

Comment: What exactly do you need? its not clear at all, if you are displaying the date as string then use `dateTime.Now.ToString("d/MM/YYYY");`, using a single `d` in the format will give you `5` for day not `05`. If that is what you need, you may specify that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to convert a string to an integer ?

Try `Convert.toInt32(date);` which will return an int... then calling `ToString()` will give you the string representation if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) or [Regex.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xwewhkd1.aspx). But it's hard to understand how to solve your problem effectively without more details/code.

Answer (score 0):

you know you could use an int for this...

```
int month = 5; //is 5 and not 05 as an example
```

why do you have a string?

Also, in c# Dates have a special variable, [the DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx/%20%22DateTime). You can store months, days, years, hours etc. in them. This might be related to what you are looking for.